# Boost: De-serializing a custom C++ object passed over ZeroMQ pull socket

Tags: c++, boost, zeromq, boost-serialization

The text I am writing here is a follow up problem that I opened up earlier in another thread at [Boost: Serializing/De-serializing a custom C++ object passed over ZeroMQ pull socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480161/boost-serializing-de-serializing-a-custom-c-object-passed-over-zeromq-pull-so). The compilation problems in the earlier thread have been resolved by using a textarchive type rather than binaryarchive but now I experience a runtime problem when de-serializing. I repeat the earlier text here with a new problem statement for your convenience. I am relatively new to C++ realm and appreciate any further help.

**Description:**

I have a C++ class named **GenericMessage** which simply holds an id and data as its members (See code snippet 2 below - GenericMessage.hxx). My intention is to serialize an instance of this class and send it via a ZeroMQ socket which implements the push pattern.

The serialization and sending task has been implemented in **class ZMQHandler** (see sendToBE function) which is placed in a header file name ZMQHandler.hxx shown in the **code snippet 3** below. This class is instantiated by **TestFE.cxx** shown in **the 4rd code snippet** below.

The receiving and de-serialization of the GenericMessage instance is implemented in **TestBE.cxx**  available in the **5th code snippet** below. My intention is to receive the GenericMessage instance over the ZMQ socket (i.e. pull socket), de-serialize it and then print its members to standard output.

**Problem Statement:**

When I run the receiver (i.e. TestBE.cxx) I verified here that I can transfer data from TestFE.cxx to TEstBE.cxx over the ZMQ socket. However, I got an exception shown in the 1st code snippet below exactly when I attempt to de-serialize the input archive at line 28 in TestBE.cxx (see the 5th code snippet very below, line 28 has been marked).

Is there something I am missing in this de-serialization procedure implemented in TestBE.cxx in code snippet 5? Why do you think I am getting this exception? Could it be that I am missing st in the serialization procedure implemented in ZMQHandler.cxx (code snippet 3 - function sendToBE). Thanks in advance.

**CODE SNIPPET 1 GDB OUTPUT & backtrace**

```
$ gdb TestBE 
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.5-ubuntu
.....
(gdb) r
 Starting program: /TestBE 
 [Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
 Using host libthread_db library "/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
 [New Thread 0xb7c12b40 (LWP 16644)]
 [New Thread 0xb7411b40 (LWP 16645)]
 Connecting to FE...
```

**!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!HERE BEGINS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!**

```
 **CHAR [22 serialization::archive 9 0 1 0
 0 1 12 Hello there!]
 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
 what():  basic_string::_S_construct null not valid**
```

**!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!HERE END !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!**

```
 Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
 0xb7fdd424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
 (gdb) bt
 #0  0xb7fdd424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
 #1  0xb7c7a1df in raise () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
 #2  0xb7c7d825 in abort () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
 #3  0xb7e608ad in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() () from /usr/lib/i386-  linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
 #4  0xb7e5e4f3 in ?? () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
 #5  0xb7e5e52f in std::terminate() () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
 #6  0xb7e5e825 in __cxa_rethrow () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
 #7  0x0804c1d4 in    boost::archive::detail::pointer_iserializer<boost::archive::text_iarchive,    GenericMessage<std::string> >::load_object_ptr (this=0x8054444, ar=..., 
 x=@0x805cb40: 0x805cb50, file_version=0) at    /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/iserializer.hpp:327
 #8  0xb7f3839d in boost::archive::detail::basic_iarchive::load_pointer(void*&,  boost::archive::detail::basic_pointer_iserializer const*,  boost::archive::detail::basic_pointer_iserializer const* (*) (boost::serialization::extended_type_info const&)) () from  /usr/lib/libboost_serialization.so.1.49.0
 #9  0x0804bea9 in    boost::archive::detail::load_pointer_type<boost::archive::text_iarchive>::invoke<GenericMes     sage<std::string>*> (ar=..., t=@0xbfffef70: 0xbfffeff8)
 at /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/iserializer.hpp:524
 #10 0x0804be55 in boost::archive::load<boost::archive::text_iarchive,                                  GenericMessage<std::string>*> (ar=..., t=@0xbfffef70: 0xbfffeff8)
 at /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/iserializer.hpp:592
 #11 0x0804be36 in   boost::archive::detail::common_iarchive<boost::archive::text_iarchive>::load_override<Gener icMessage<std::string>*> (this=0xbfffef84, t=@0xbfffef70: 0xbfffeff8)
  at /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/common_iarchive.hpp:66
 #12 0x0804be14 in  boost::archive::basic_text_iarchive<boost::archive::text_iarchive>::load_override<GenericMe ssage<std::string>*> (this=0xbfffef84, t=@0xbfffef70: 0xbfffeff8)
  at /usr/include/boost/archive/basic_text_iarchive.hpp:65
 #13 0x0804bdf2 in boost::archive::text_iarchive_impl<boost::archive::text_iarchive>::load_override<GenericMes sage<std::string>*> (this=0xbfffef84, t=@0xbfffef70: 0xbfffeff8)
  at /usr/include/boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp:82
 #14 0x0804bcec in      boost::archive::detail::interface_iarchive<boost::archive::text_iarchive>::operator>> <GenericMessage<std::string>*> (this=0xbfffef84, t=@0xbfffef70: 0xbfffeff8)
 at /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/interface_iarchive.hpp:60
 #15 0x0804b2a1 in main () at TestBE.cxx:28
```

**CODE SNIPPET 2 (GenericMessage.hxx)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>

template <class T>
class GenericMessage {
public:
  GenericMessage(): 
    beId(-1), 
    data(NULL)
  {}

  GenericMessage(int id, T msg): 
    beId(id), 
    data(msg)
  {}

  ~GenericMessage(){}

  T getData()
  {
    return data;
  }


  std::string toString()
  {
     std::ostringstream ss;
     ss << getBeId();
     std::string ret =  ss.str();

    return ret;
  }

  void setBeId(int id)
  {
    beId = id;
  }

  int getBeId()
  {
    return beId;
  }


  private:
      friend class boost::serialization::access;

  int beId;
  T data;


  template <class Archive>
  void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
  {
      ar & beId;
      ar & data;
  }

 };
```

**CODE SNIPPET 3 (ZmqHandler.hxx)**

```
#include "zmq.hpp"
#include "GenericMessage.hxx"
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cassert>

template <class A>
class ZmqHandler {
public:

ZmqHandler():
mContext(1),
mOutbHandlerSocket(mContext, ZMQ_PUSH)
{    
    mOutbHandlerSocket.bind ("tcp://*:5555");       
}


~ZmqHandler() {}

void sendToBE(GenericMessage<A> *theMsg)
{
   std::ostringstream archive_stream;
   boost::archive::text_oarchive archive(archive_stream);

   try
   {
     archive << theMsg;
   } catch (boost::archive::archive_exception& ex) {
      std::cout << "Archive Exception during deserializing:" << std::endl;
      std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;           
   } catch (int e) {
       std::cout << "EXCEPTION " << e << std::endl; 
   }

   std::string outbound_data_ = archive_stream.str();
   const char * buf = outbound_data_.c_str();    
   int len = strlen((const char*)buf);
   std::cout << "LENGTH [" << len << "]" << std::endl;

   zmq::message_t msgToSend(len);

   memcpy ((char *) msgToSend.data(), buf, len);

   if(memcmp((char *) msgToSend.data(), buf, len) != 0)
   {
     std::cout << "memcpy error!" << std::endl;
   }

   mOutbHandlerSocket.send(msgToSend);
   std::cout << "SENT request: [" << theMsg->toString() << "]" << std::endl;
 }   

  private:  
     zmq::context_t mContext;
     zmq::socket_t mOutbHandlerSocket;         
 };
```

**CODE SNIPPET 4 (TestFE.cxx)**

```
  #include "ZmqHandler.hxx"

  int main ()
  {
     ZmqHandler<std::string> zmqHandler;
     int counter = 1;

     while(1)
     {  
        std::string data = "Hello there!\0";
        GenericMessage<std::string> msg(counter, data);
        zmqHandler.sendToBE(&msg);
        counter++;
       sleep(1);
      }

    return 0;
 }
```

**CODE SNIPPET 5 (TestBE.cxx)**

```
 #include "zmq.hpp"
 #include "GenericMessage.hxx"
 #include <fstream>

 int main ()
 {
    //  Prepare our context and socket
    zmq::context_t context (1);
    zmq::socket_t socket (context, ZMQ_PULL);

    std::cout << "Connecting to FE..." << std::endl;
    socket.connect ("tcp://localhost:5555");

    while(1){
       zmq::message_t reply;
       socket.recv (&reply);

       const char *buf = static_cast<const char*>(reply.data());
       std::cout << "CHAR [" << buf << "]" << std::endl;

       std::string input_data_(buf); 
       std::istringstream archive_stream(input_data_);
       boost::archive::text_iarchive archive(archive_stream);
       GenericMessage<std::string> *theMsg;

       try
       {
       /* !!!!!!!!!! LINE 28 is the following !!!!!!!!!!*/
         archive >> theMsg;
       } catch (boost::archive::archive_exception& ex) {
          std::cout << "Archive Exception during deserializing:" << std::endl;
          std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;           
       } catch (int e) {
          std::cout << "EXCEPTION " << e << std::endl; 
       }

       std::cout << "ID" << theMsg->getBeId() << std::endl; 
       std::cout << "Data" << theMsg->getData() << std::endl; 

     }

    return 0;
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared `theMsg` as a pointer (`GenericMessage<std::string> *theMsg;`).

Try changing that line to `GenericMessage<std::string> theMsg;`.`

**The real source of your exception**

In the `GenericMessage` default constructor, you initialize `data` with `NULL`.  However, you aren't allowed to initialize a `std::string` with a `NULL` pointer.  Don't initialize your `data` member in the default constructor.

```
GenericMessage()
: beId(-1) 
{}
```

As long as your type `T` has a default constructor, the compiler will handle its initialization when the template is generated.

**(hopefully) helpful hint #1**

The data buffer in a `zmq::message_t` is (generally) not NULL-terminated.  After you receive the message, be careful about how you convert the buffer to a string.

```
// snip
zmq::message_t reply;
socket.recv (&reply);

const char *buf = static_cast<const char*>(reply.data());
std::cout << "CHAR [" << buf << "]" << std::endl;

//std::string input_data_(buf);  // assumes a null-term string
std::string input_data_( buf, reply.size() ); 
// snip
```

**(hopefully) helpful hint #2**

Also, I noticed something in **ZmqHandler.hxx**.

```
// snip
std::string outbound_data_ = archive_stream.str();
const char * buf = outbound_data_.c_str();    
int len = strlen((const char*)buf);
std::cout << "LENGTH [" << len << "]" << std::endl;

zmq::message_t msgToSend(len);

memcpy ((char *) msgToSend.data(), buf, len);

if(memcmp((char *) msgToSend.data(), buf, len) != 0)
{
  std::cout << "memcpy error!" << std::endl;
}
// snip
```

You don't need to check the results of the memcpy (unless you want to check its return value).  The whole block could be changed to something like this:

```
std::string outbound_data_ = archive_stream.str();
// no need to use the c-style string function 'strlen'
int len = outbound_data_.length();
std::cout << "LENGTH [" << len << "]" << std::endl;

zmq::message_t msgToSend(len);
memcpy( msgToSend.data(), outbound_data_.data(), len );
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I still get the error that I have mentioned earlier in the 1st code snippet above. Can there be st more I am missing?

Comment: Thanks. It works now but with some other problems. In the last two lines of TestBE.cxx where I print the ID and Data of the GeNericMessage object, I got nothing for the data field. Also, there comes some wird characters with question marks where I print the content of the transfered string. Do you have any idea on why this is happening? Thanks a lot.


0 39 12 Hello there!���]

ID0

Data

Comment: I see something off in **TestFE.cxx**.  You initialize `data` like so: `std::string data = "Hello there!\0";`.  You can just say `std::string data( "Hello there!" );`.  There's no need to explicitly include the null-term in your string literal.  The string handles that for you.  I don't know that this is your problem, but it probably doesn't the situation.

Comment: Yes, I already removed that new line char but it does not solve the issue. Any other suggestion?

Comment: `\0` is a NULL char, not a newline.  It seems the new issue is separate from the initial question (the `std::logic_error` exception).  My suggestion is to accept the answer and then ask a new question.  You can link that question to this one to make other folks aware of the history.  Make sure to update the code, but it should be mostly copy/paste.

Comment: thanks for the explanations, I am opening a new thread for the new issue.

Comment: The follow up problem has been opened at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14650104/follow-up-boost-deserializaztion-of-a-custom-c-object-passed-over-zeromq-pu